# Multiple Aggregations on same level in Elasticsearch-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I am trying to perform multiple aggregations at the same level with ElasticSearch using the elasticsearch-rails and elasticsearch-model gems.

In the query hash that I am generating, I have the following -

```
    def query_hash(params, current_person = nil, manager_id = nil)
      aggs = {}
      aggs[:home_country_id] = {terms: {field: "home_country_id"}}
      aggs[:home_region_id] = {terms: {field: "home_region_id"}}
      {
        sort: [ { created_at: { order: "desc" } }, id: { order: "desc" } ],
        aggs: aggs
      }
    end
```

The response I stored in an object es_response.

When I search for both the aggregations, I can only find the last one in the response.

es_response.response["aggregrations"] only has the response of the latest aggregation object, `home_region_id`.

I couldn't find much documentation on the ES Reference on structuring multiple aggregations on the same level although there was a lot about nesting aggregations.

How can I fix this?

My ES version is 5.1